# Use variables of one function to another function in python

Tags: python, function, inheritance

I have a function:

```
def main():
    bla bla bla...
    output_name = 'Employee'
    bla bla bla...
```

I have another function:

```
def tocsv(path):
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(path)

names = xls_file.sheet_names    

for items in names:     
    df = xls_file.parse(items)
    out_file = output_name + '.csv'
    df.to_csv(out_file, sep='\t',index=False,header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE )
```

I need the name of the file from the variable 'output_name' defined in the first function main(). So that my output file will be named as "Employee.csv" . How can I do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Variables defined inside a function are local to that function. If you want to use a variable  defined inside a function elsewhere, you should `return` that variable to the calling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are stored in local scope if it's defined inside a function. To use a variable in multiple functions, there's two ways of doing that,

First: set `output_name` as a global variable:

```
def main():
    global output_name
    output_name = 'Employee'
```

Second: pass the argument along when calling `tocsv()`:

```
def main():
    output_name = 'Employee'
    tocsv(path, output_name) # if you're calling it from main

def tocsv(path, output_name): # and set tocsv to take output_name as an argument
    # do stuff
```